# Hwo can I tell vscode to scan only one subdirectory for go tests?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

We have a project which is mainly written in python, with a `tools/` subdirectory which contains code for tools written in go.

Currently: if I go on the "Testing" tab of vscode, vscode apparently spends quite some time scanning our complete project looking for go test files.

I would like vscode to only scan `tools/`, which is much smaller.

Another point that could direct the search for tests is: `tools/` is currently the only go module (directory with a `go.mod` file at its root) in our entire project.

I tried looking at vscode settings for go, but couldn't find what I am looking for.

Is there a setting I missed somewhere ?

Comment: A simple workaround would be to add only the Go code root directory `tools/` in your VSCode workspace, without any Python parts outside, to do the testing.

Comment: the goal is to use vscode as an IDE :) (for the python part too)